# No seasonal plot using ETS

Tags: r

I have a time series of 'bicoal.tons' which contains measurements of annual coal production from 1920 to 1968. This data is saved under the name of `time_series`.

```
Time Series:
Start = 1920 
End = 1968 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 569 416 422 565 484 520 573 518 501 505 468 382 310 334 359 372 439 446 349 395
[21] 461 511 583 590 620 578 534 631 600 438 516 534 467 457 392 467 500 493 410 412
[41] 416 403 422 459 467 512 534 552 545
```

For decomposition, I used the code `plot(ets(time_series))` and got the following outcome.
[image]

As you can see, I cannot find the seasonal nor the random effect plot. Is there something I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is annual so seasonality does not apply (i.e. season is *within* a year).

Assuming you have a monthly / quarterly / semi-annual data, then `ets()` may pick a model without seasonality. To force seasonality, you can do something like below (A = additive, see `?ets`):

```
plot(ets(dat, model = "ZZA"))
```